# What is the latest edition of Knuth's "Computers & Typesetting" Series?

Tags: books, knuth

I would like to buy Knuth's ["millenium boxed set"](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html#boxed) of Computers & Typesetting, but I can't figure out if there is more than one edition. The "Computers & Typesetting" books were originally published in 1986. Were they published as a boxed set then, or are any box sets available now the "Millenium Edition"?

Comment: While Knuth is clearly very important in the TeX world, I'm not sure this is on topic here. It's not about TeX or a TeX tool _per se_.

Comment: You could probably just ask the folks in chat about this.

Comment: AFAICT, there have been two editions of this five-volume box set -- the first on 1/1/2001, the second in late 2001. The errata list (last update: 3/18/2008), covering all five volumes, is located at http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde-err.ps.gz.

Comment: Good enough for me, thanks for researching!